# Can I update column value into a trigger when insert event happens?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using SQL Server 2008. Can I update a column value in the same table on which an insert trigger happens?

I.e., can I use this code?

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Table1_Insert_Table1name
ON Table1name
FOR INSERT AS

BEGIN

 UPDATE @NEW
    SET COLUMN = 3;

END
GO
```

If "No", how can make this happen?

Comment: I don't understand what you're wanting to do -- that, or why you wouldn't use a DEFAULT constraint on the column...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Yeah, +1 to that. If all the OP wants is to provide a default value he should be doing it in the table definition. If he's instead wanting to make sure that a user can't provide a different value for an inserted record a trigger may be the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Insert_Trigger (
    my_id INT NOT NULL,
    my_string VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Insert_Trigger PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_id)
)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tri_Test_Insert_Trigger
ON Test_Insert_Trigger FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE T
    SET my_string = CAST(I.my_id AS VARCHAR(20))
    FROM
        INSERTED I
    INNER JOIN dbo.Test_Insert_Trigger T ON
        T.my_id = I.my_id
END
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Insert_Trigger (my_id) VALUES (1)
SELECT * FROM dbo.Test_Insert_Trigger
```

As OMG Ponies points out though, in many cases a `DEFAULT` constraint is what you'll really want here.

Comment: Did you try it? It's a pretty simple change to the script above. I'll give you a hint though: yes.

Comment: My friend,
Can I make this code?
<code>
UPDATE INSERTED
SET  ID = 3;

Comment: @Luciano: You can't modify the `inserted` table in a trigger.

Comment: That IS what I should know!
Thanks.

Comment: You can't update the system `INSERTED` table, but you can update the table which caused the insert trigger to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. There is no problem with your code since an `UPDATE` statement won't interfere with the `INSERT` you're overriding. You would want something like this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Column = 3
WHERE Table.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
  AND Table.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM deleted);
```

This is assuming your table has an `ID` column.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you don't need that second test (`NOT IN deleted`) in a `FOR INSERT` trigger. Although it doesn't change anything, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Use After Insert Trigger For Update Rows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Table1_Insert_Table1name ON Table1name 
    AFTER INSERT 
AS  BEGIN   
    UPDATE Table1
    SET COLUMN = 3
    Where ...  
END 
GO
```

Comment: The OP uses has declared their trigger as `FOR INSERT`, which is the same, because `AFTER INSERT` = `FOR INSERT` [in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx "CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)"). The issue has to do with the incorrect updating.